# Problem with custom scrollbar when it is called more than once on the same page

Tags: views, javascript

I making my custom module that works through Views and I have problem with one part of it. In one part, when I have longer text, custom scrollbar appears, and it works without any problems, but when I put more than one Views block on the same page scrollbar appears more then one (when I put two blocks it appears twice, on three blocks it appears three times, etc.).

There is my tpl.php file for View where scrollbar is called (this is the whole file with all other elements):

```
<?php if (!empty($title)): ?>
  <h3><?php print $title; ?></h3>
<?php endif; ?>
<div id="<?php print $view_id; ?>" class="timeline<?php print ' ' . $gso_line_style; print ' ' . $gso_nav_style; print ' ' . $bso_button_type; ?>">
  <?php foreach ($rows as $id => $row): ?>
    <?php print $row; ?>
  <?php endforeach; ?>
</div>
<?php drupal_add_js('(function($){
    var test = false;
    $(window).load(function() {
      if(!test)
        timeline_init_'.$view_id.'($(document));
    });
    function timeline_init_'.$view_id.'($this) {
      $this.find(".scrollable-content").mCustomScrollbar();
      $this.find("a[rel^=\'prettyPhoto\']").prettyPhoto();

      $this.find("#'.$view_id.'").timeline({
        itemMargin : '.$gso_item_margin.',
        scrollSpeed : '.$go_scroll_speed.',
        easing : "'.$go_easing.'",
        openTriggerClass : \''.$gso_read_more.'\',
        swipeOn : true,
        startItem : "last",
        yearsOn : '.$go_hide_years.',
        hideTimeline : '.$gso_hide_timeline.',
        hideControles : '.$gso_hide_navigation.',
        closeText : "'.$bso_close_button_text.'",
        closeItemOnTransition: '.$go_close_item_on_transition.'
    });

    $this.find("#'.$view_id.'").on("ajaxLoaded.timeline", function(e){
      var scrCnt = e.element.find(".scrollable-content");
      scrCnt.height(scrCnt.parent().height() - scrCnt.parent().children("h2").height() - parseInt(scrCnt.parent().children("h2").css("margin-bottom")));
      scrCnt.mCustomScrollbar({theme:"light-thin"});
      e.element.find("a[rel^=\'prettyPhoto\']").prettyPhoto();
      e.element.find(".timeline_rollover_bottom").timelineRollover("bottom");
    });
  }
  })(jQuery);', array('type' => 'inline', 'scope' => 'footer', 'weight' => 5)); ?>
```

Can you help me with this or give me some idea how to solve the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use Drupal behaviors like

```
(function ($) {

  Drupal.behaviors.exampleModule = {
    attach: function (context, settings) {
      $('.example', context).click(function () {
        $(this).next('ul').toggle('show');
      });
    }
  };

})(jQuery);
```

for more info go through [Link](https://www.drupal.org/node/756722)